# Can't create 5Ghz wifi hotspot on ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, hot-spot, ralink

I recently bought an RT3572 chip based usb wifi adapter, but i can't seem to be able to create a 5Ghz hotspot, when i try to in ubuntu 22.04, this is the output of dmesg:

[image: Output of sudo dmesg]

here's my hotspot configuration (wlx0013eff709bd is what ubuntu gave name to RT3572 adapter):

[image: hotspot config]

using `iw` command does confirm it can use AP mode

[image: supported modes]

plus here are the list of supported frequencies in 5Ghz band:

[image: 5ghz supported frequencies]

incase if it helps, my country code is PK

P.S. i also tried plugging this adapter into my raspberry piOS running raspAP, and tried creating a 5Ghz hotspot in there, and this is the output of log file of hostapd (here, RT3572 is wlan1):

```
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Channel 36 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3 NO-IR
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an access point in the 5Ghz WiFi access point running with ubuntu 20.04 and hostapd (Ubuntu server version – no GUI).

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 the access point did not work anymore.
The conclusion after reading a lot of pages is:
There is a regulatory change (country dependent) that requires other 802.11 standards that are not supported by my hardware.

This can be clearly seen in the last log you provided:

```
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
```

**Verification of the answer:**

Install 20.00 instead of 22.04 and the AP will work in 5Ghz

**Options:**

- Fake your county code and try to find a country that allows a 5Ghz AP
- Get other hardware.
- move to 2.4 Ghz

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, i am currently installing the ubuntu 20.04.5 as we speak, will update later after checking whether 5Ghz works there or not,   i wanted to ask another question, is how can i find which country code would work to enable wifi and what would be consequences of using a wrong country code, will it cause any other issues?

Comment: there are many county code lists, but I'm looking for this information too.

Comment: i see, btw do you happen to know any guides which tell you how to create an AP on ubuntu on virtualbox? , i don't have a free device at hand atm on which i can install ubuntu 20.04, my laptop is already running both windows 10 an ubuntu 22.4 atm

Comment: it is a bad idea to try to use a virtual server as AP. Why: You wil not use the linux HW driver of the virtual Server, instead you use the driver on the host. That's a waste of time.

Comment: and one more infos: 1) there is a "new" daemon which should replace hoastapd called iwd. it is present in 22.10 I' did not test 22.04.

Comment: i see, thanks for info, another question, is the "new" daemon named iwd better than hostapd and will it fix the 5Ghz issue?

Comment: Also, i did managed to run the 5Ghz on my raspberry pi, by setting the region as CN and channel to 149, but the performance is terrible, only 20Mbps, probably because of 20Mhz transmission speed  of channel 149, I'll try channel 155 later at 80Mhz and will update you on the results